# Why can't stl types resolved in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Recently I've installed Eclipse Juno with CDT 8.1 on Ubuntu 12.10, but even the basic HelloWorld project shows errors.   and std can't be resolved. After I add /usr/include/c++/4.7/ to the include path,  and headers like  can be resolved, but std::cout and other std things still can't be resolved. Are there any solutions other than use indigo?

Comment: Are these just Eclipse editor warnings or actual compiler errors?

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/

Comment: Why has nobody answered this? It's driving me nuts!